# Connection Refused after setting maxInMemorySize for Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a spring boot applicantion that makes a get call using Webflux

```
public Optional<String> getStatusUpdate(final String id, final String requestId, final TypeHeader typeHeaderValue) {

return web.get().uri("/{uri}/" + id).headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(getToken()))
    .header("requestId", requestId)
    .header("type", typeHeaderValue.toString())
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebClientException("Client Error for getStatusUpdate()")))
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebServerException("Server Error for getStatusUpdate()")))
    .bodyToMono(String.class).blockOptional();
```

}

I expecting a load that exceeds the 265KB so I increased the buffer size to 5000KB

```
public Optional<String> getStatusUpdate(final String bundleId, final String requestId, final TypeHeader typeHeaderValue) {
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
    .create()
    .wiretap(true);
final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
    .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(6000 * 1024))
    .build();
WebClient web = WebClient.builder().filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
  exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
  exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
}).exchangeStrategies(strategies).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
return web.get().uri("/Bundles/" + bundleId).headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(getToken()))
    .header("requestId", requestId)
    .header("type", typeHeaderValue.toString())
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebClientException("Client Error for getStatusUpdate()")))
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebServerException("Server Error for getStatusUpdate()")))
    .bodyToMono(String.class).blockOptional();
```

}

Now I started to get Connection refused from the server or to be specific I am getting the following:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
```

I tried to get the response but I cannot even make the connection. It doesn't matter to what value I set the maxInMemorySize I cannot make the connection. I wonder if this is something on the server side? Or is this something to do with the way I am configuring the WebCLient?